# present simple to express a specific statement?

Tags: present-continuous

> The car doesn’t start. If you get in Tom and I will give you a push.

Why not **is starting** as it is a temporary state for a car not a general statement

The sentence comes from [this worksheet](https://www.english-grammar.at/worksheets/tenses/t16.pdf) (the answer is shown on Page 2)

Answer (score 1):

I think *the car is not  starting* is possible and correct.

> **When I went to the Railway station, the train was starting**.

If the car has not started even after repeated trials, we  can say:

> **The car won't start**.

or:

> **The car is not starting.**

**The car does not start** may mean that it never starts as it may talk about a permanent state.

Here is a link which shows the usage of   *start* in [Oxford Learners Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/start_1).

Comment: I think your suggestion of "The car won't start" would be a better answer for the worksheet. +1

Comment: Won't start is better than doesn't start or is not starting and why

Comment: @user5577.It does not start  is a fact. so it is not suitable.If you make just one or two trials  you may  say, the engine is not  starting..If you believe that the refuses to start even after repeated trials, it is better to say, the engine wont start.